# Angular2 ngClass: How to choose a class conditionally?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have the following code in Angular 2. I want that only one div element will get a class style 'chosen' based on the value of 'service.mode'. After writing this code, I found out that all div elements get the class "chosen", even though 'service.mode' equals to 'slots'.

```
<header>
  <div [ngClass] = "{'chosen': 'service.mode == \'featured\''}"> Featured Games</div>
  <div [ngClass] = "{'chosen': 'service.mode == \'slots\''}"> Slot Games </div>
  <div [ngClass] = "{'chosen': 'service.mode == \'card\''}"> Card Games </div>
  <div [ngClass] = "{'chosen': 'service.mode == \'table\''}"> Table Games </div>
</header>
```

Do you know what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
<header>
    <div [ngClass] = "{'chosen': service.mode == 'featured'}"> Featured Games</div>
    <div [ngClass] = "{'chosen': service.mode == 'slots'}"> Slot Games </div>
    <div [ngClass] = "{'chosen': service.mode == 'card'}"> Card Games </div>
    <div [ngClass] = "{'chosen': service.mode == 'table'}"> Table Games </div>
</header>
```

Don't know why you used `\`, use it inside `''` if you want to compare `service.mode` with `featured\` for example.